# i got an error message about Regex.Replace function

Tags: c#

[image]

I am building a weather forecast window form.
it has to be retrieved from the weatherForecasts txt file.
what if it says 'value cannot be null', what can i use instead of ""
by the way, I didn't save any data in weaterForecasts txt file. That's why I put "".

and I cannot save data if this doesn't work.

I am a beginner, please tell me how to solve this. and sorry about that, my English is bad.

Comment: Always do a `null` check before doing an operation over it. Either the File Object is empty or the Content of the File could be empty.

Comment: What might be the case in this situation is that you are using ReadFile.ReadLine() as input to Regex.Replace(), but it's value can be null if reached end of file. Try to use null check like this: Regex.Replace( ReadFile.ReadLine() ?? "", "City: ", "")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message says the first parameter of the Regex.Replace method is null. This parameter is called "input" here. This happens for example if your file ("Readfile") is empty.

You have to store the output of ReadLine() in a variable and check if it is okay with the String.IsNullOrEmpty() method. If this check returns false (meaning the string isn't null) you can do the Regex.Replace() call.

Here's the essence:

```
string line = Readfile.ReadLine();
if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(line) == false)
{
  txtCity.Text = Regex.Replace(line, "City: ", String.Empty);
}
```

As an alternative for an empty string "" you can use String.Empty.

Optional:
To improve further, you can research about exception handling when accessing files and have a look into the using statement:

```
using(StreamReader Readfile = File.OpenText("..."))
{
...
}
```